# Highcharts: Network graph: marker radius = number of connections

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In a highcharts network graph:
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/network-graph
, I can't see a method of dynamically sizing the marker radius to match the number of connections that marker has.

For example:

```
data: [
    ['Jim', 'Michael'],
    ['Jim', 'Pam'],
    ['Jim', 'Dwight'],
    ['Michael', 'Pam'],
]
```

we would expect to see:

- Jim have a marker radius of 3
- Michael have a marker radius of 2
- Pam have a marker radius of 2
- Dwight have a marker radius of 1

https://jsfiddle.net/3140g2wq/12/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to calculate the radius yourself by iterating through your data links and counting up the number of connections each node has.

```
Highcharts.addEvent(
    Highcharts.Series,
    'afterSetOptions',
    function (e) {
            
            let nodeCounts = {};
      
            //count connections for each From or To node
            e.options.data.forEach(function (link) {
                nodeCounts[link[0]] = (nodeCounts[link[0]] || 0) + 1;
                nodeCounts[link[1]] = (nodeCounts[link[1]] || 0) + 1;
            });

            let radiusFactor = 3; //radius multiplier to graphically enlarge nodes

            //map each nodeCount to a node object setting the radius
            e.options.nodes = Object.keys(nodeCounts).map(function (id) {                   
                return {
                id: id,
                marker: {   radius: nodeCounts[id] * radiusFactor }
                };
            });
        }    
);
```

Comment: You can set their individual color through similar means